# RxJava Sqlite Insert returns a Zero arg constructor error

Tags: android, mvvm, android-sqlite, rx-java2

When launching the activity I get a error:

```
  java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.example.ui.activities.NoteActivity> has no zero argument constructor
```

Could someone please help me fix this? Please see the class code below.
Quick summary of the code: it's trying to do an insert into an SQlite database by calling noteDao.insert(note); Note is instantiated and the values are set in the constructor as seen in the code below. But I think I havent initialised the noteDao properly as the IDE shows it as being greyed out and underlined stating its declared but not initialised. but I don't know how to fix this.

```
private EditText automaticThoughtET;
@Inject
ViewModelProviderFactory providerFactory;

@NonNull
private final NoteDao noteDao;

@Inject
public NoteActivity(@NonNull NoteDao noteDao) {
    this.noteDao = noteDao; }


private SharedPreferences loginPref, workoutPref;

private int userId, therapistId, distortions = 0;

private FloatingActionButton nextButton;

private static final String TAG = "sqCbtId";

private int sqCbtId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_note);

    // Initialising editText form the xml file
    automaticThoughtET = findViewById(R.id.noteThoughtInput);

    // Initialising the nextButton form the xml file
    nextButton = findViewById(R.id.noteActivityButton);

    nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Note note = new Note(userId, therapistId, "Test", 0, "", "", postedWorkout);
            try {
                noteDao.insert(note);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This part:

```
@Inject
public NoteActivity(@NonNull NoteDao noteDao) {
    this.noteDao = noteDao;
}
```

is a No-No. You do not mess with activity constructors. You do not override activity cosntructors. You do not write new activity constructors.

Injecting stuff to activity is being done other ways, generally done in `onCreate()` method. For example, assuming that you are using Dagger, something like this: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Dagger/article.html#exercise_androiddagger_di

Comment: If i delete that then it tells me that noteDao is null, I dont know how to make it not be null

Comment: Have you read my whole answer? Injection in activities is done from onCreate() method and I've linked you one of many tutorials how to do it. The idea is to call injector in onCreate() and injector will fill in all of your dependencies that you want to inject.